# Managing exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to handle the exceptions and how to deal with them in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150330/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-the-exceptions-and-how-to-deal-with-them-in-asp-ne)

I build a web site with ASP.NET MVC. In the inner functions I deal with logic, against the db etc. Inside I use try catch for unexpected exceptions.

Because I need to know about the exceptions to return message to the client I need to use the try catch also in the controller who calls the inner functions. Is that heavy on performance?

What is the best way to handle exceptions in my site?

Answer (score 1):

each time you try-catch an exception it have a significant cost. Ideally you only should use a try-catch for real exceptions. If you use it to return messages (as part as a normal workflow), it will have an impact on your performance (and it's really a bad practice).

Example:

- you need to try-catch any external dependency: database connection,
  webservice, wcf, ... You can also do it with the *using* clausule.
- you **do not** need to try-catch something you can control with
  logic. For instance, a username and password string.Empty (you can
  validate the imput data, not relying on the try-catch).

If you are not going to control the exception or take action, do not catch and let the upper layer to deal with the exception. A good example of taking action is free resources on the finally clausule, rethrowing the exception on the catch. That have a performance impact, but It also have leaving unreleased resources.

Exception management strategy is important in a big project. Cannot be a big deal in a simple application, but if you are going to receive a huge load, you should think careful who will be the responsible of dealing with the exception.